# Javascript List not inserting more than three elements. (Eloquent Javascript)

Tags: javascript, list, data-structures

I am trying to implement List assignment in Eloquent Javascript. But I am not able to insert more than thee values. Here is my code. Please help.

```
var list = null;
var insert = function(element){
    if(list == null){
        list = { value : element, rest: null};
    }else{
        temp = list;
        while(temp.rest != null){
            temp = temp.rest;
        }
        temp.rest = { value : element, rest: null};
    }
    console.log(list);
}
var array = [1,2,3,4];
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    insert(array[i]);
}
```

When inserting the 4th element, I am getting an `[Object]` value. Here is my output.

```
{ value: 1, rest: null }
{ value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: null } }
{ value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null } } }
{ value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: [Object] } } }
```

I am not able to find the reason. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the developer console is showing [Object] you try :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(list))
```

instead of

```
console.log(list)
```

Comment: I tried it earlier before posting, but there was a typo in `stringify` method.